# Only one cookie available in response from Mule HTTP operation-based Connector

Tags: http, cookies, mule, setcookie

I'm trying to get a project that was made in Mule 3.4 working in Mule 3.7. In Mule 3.4, using the HTTP endpoint-based Connector it was possible to retrieve multiple cookies from response messages by using:

```
    Object cookieObj = message.getInboundProperty("Set-Cookie");
    String cookieValSchoolname = CookieHelper.getCookieValueFromCookies (cookieObj, "schoolname");
    String cookieValJSessionId = CookieHelper.getCookieValueFromCookies(cookieObj, "JSESSIONID");
```

In Mule 3.4, using the HTTP endpoint-based Connector, the inbound property "Set-Cookie" contained an array of all the cookies that are set with Set-Cookie in the http header.

However when I use the same code with the new HTTP operation-based Connector, the inbound property "Set-Cookie" only contains the first cookie and not an array with all cookies.

Can anybody tell me how I can access all cookies using the new HTTP Connector?
Maybe there is a way to retrieve the raw http header, to parse that?

The only other inbound properties the message has are content-length, http.reason, http.status, content-type, server and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8790). You can check the fix versions there. Cannot think of any workarounds unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I should upgrade to Mule 3.7.2. Should  I download that manually? Because in Anypoint Studio the last Mule ESB Server Runtime I can download is 3.7.1.

Comment: I think that depends on your Studio version, I can see it under Anypoint Studio Update Site (http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/updates).

Comment: I can't see it at the moment. I use Anypoint Studio 5.3.0 the Build Id is: 201509170844. I am now downloading "Studio including 3.7.2-EE runtime" from the Salesforce customer portal.

Comment: With the 3.7.2-EE runtime message.getInboundProperty("set-cookie"); does indeed return an ArrayList with cookies.

Comment: Unfortunately now the CookieHelper.getCookieValueFromCookies function does not work anymore. I get the error:Invalid cookiesObject. Only class org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie[] and interface java.util.Map are supported. Is this also a bug?

Comment: Hard to say. CookieHelper is part of the old HTTP, so it is meant to work with that. The new module must be handling it differently (I think it just gives you a List of strings) so it won't and shouldn't necessarily work with it.

Comment: Thanks, like I just posted in the Mulesoft forum, I now parse the array elements with parseCookiesAsAclient.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Anypoint studio is concerned, mulesoft blog says "Anypoint Studio 5.3 with Mule 3.7.2 released!". If possible have that downloaded and do let us know if the issue is fixed. It might help others too.